# what is different between Equatable and Freezed in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm new to flutter and I was following some youtube tutorials and I got wonder
what is different between Equatable and Freezed in flutter?
I mean purpose of using it is same but I just want to know in which case we better use Equatable or Freezed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I mean purpose of using it is same

Not at all.  Equatable is "An abstract class that helps to implement equality without needing to explicitly override == and hashCode.".  Freezed is "Code generation for immutable classes that has a simple syntax/API without compromising on the features."

Sure, they both override == and hashCode, but after that, they are very different.  Equatable is a mixin to give a consistent, easy == and hashCode (although not necessarily the most efficient).  Freezed is a build system that can use annotations to make immutable classes.  Definitely different.

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, but could you maybe explain more about in which case we use Equatable and Freezed ?

Comment: Do you need immutable values, and are willing to deal with the compile-time building for that?  Use Freezed.  Do you need to save a little time writing == and hashCode to react to the member values of your class?  Use Equatable.

Comment: that is so perfect answer! thanks a lot !

Comment: And now, for the best of all worlds, there's now https://pub.dev/packages/fast_immutable_collections, which promises decent speed, immutable collections, deep equality, *and* no build step.  Almost too good to be true!